# WCF windows authentication when domain controller is not accessible

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-authentication, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I've a WCF service using windows authentication:
This service is available via an https://subdomain.mydomain.com/MyService.svc
The current configuration is:

```
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding  name="SecureNetTcpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  <netTcpBinding>
```

The client use a SPN to authenticate the server (spn:MyService/subdomain.mydomain.com).

When the user is connected via VPN to the domain, the authentication work fine. But when the VPN is disconnected, he can't connect: An error message say that domain controller can't be found:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later
```

So could someone tell me if it's possible to make this scenario possible ?

UPDATE 1:
The scenario I would like, is to use the windows authentication like in browser: the browser send the windows authentication, and don't need to have a connection to the Domain controller. It works with VPN closed.

Comment: This is a networking question I believe, but here's a short stab at it -- "no". It sounds like the domain is only an "internal" domain and the network/firewall/infrastructure does not allow connections to that domain from outside the local network. You will have to work with your networking team to explore alternate scenarios.

Comment: Edited my question: The scenario I would like, is to use the windows authentication like in browser: the browser send the windows authentication, and don't need to have a connection to the Domain controller. It works with VPN closed.

Comment: That kind of doesn't make sense does it? How are you going to authenticate to a domain controller the browser can't talk to?

Comment: Because the laptop belong to the domain -event not currently connected to- and the server can talk to the domain. For web app it already works out-of-the-box with the browser, so my question is just to know if it's possible to do it using WCF. This is a WCF specific question, not a network or architecture question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the answer is hidden in your question.
As SPN needs some configuration to work ([check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/how-a-service-registers-its-spns)), when the VPN is connected that configuration works fine, when disconnected it doesn't.

Your problem is relying to the connection to the authentication service ([check this too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-iwa#reason-integrated-windows-authentication-fails)). When you say that browser works, I assume that a third party application doesn't?

Continuing with this assumption and since the browser is working fine (I suppose you invoke the wcf endpoints through the enabled web broswer test method interfaces), check if the browser is using some proxy, or not. Check also from different web browsers.

One think that worth doing is try calling the service using soapui or other soap wcf capabilities app with VPN closed and see what happens.
Also, check for any firewall settings that may not allow unknown agents or apps to pass through up to your SPN. Both on the client and server sides.

This is a good point to start investigating.

Comment: I think you're right, problem should come from SPN. But I don't know how to workaround this. I'm trying to configure it using a dns identity (instead of spn), but it doesn't work.
Concerning browser, it was just an example of "no need to have a DC" to answer previous comment. Browser just use default http windows auth to call api in the same IIS application than WCF.

Comment: You cant do something with SPN as I understand. Windows is not using any auth, the browser (eg. IE) supports windows authentication natively and the server is set also to support this auth type also. So, your wcf (on the client that runs), should use proper configuration to support windows authentication and the user under the prosess it will run, should be the same like the one you try when using a browser. If you have a windows service, it should run under the authorized user. Give me more details of your case if you like.